# Importing JSON into Android app from authenticated web page

Tags: android, json, authentication, authorization

Here's the scenario.  A user has an account on a site I have no control over.  My app needs JSON data from http://url/json.  The JSON only displays if the user is logged in.

Basically, my app will:
1. Pop up the login page (Either in a web view or even the browser if possible)
2. They'll enter the credentials (I don't want or need these)
3. I'll use the authenticated session to grab the JSON data.
(Reformatting and presenting the JSON data is the entire reason the user is using this app, so they'd be fine with this.)

Without specific external facing APIs, is this even possible?  A Webview/browser has access to the data, so I was thinking that maybe my app could too (with explicit permission from the user).

I haven't started, so I'm open to most any flavor of Android development.  I was leaning toward React-Native for the multi-platform aspect as well as it would be somewhat useful to learn for my job.  However, it might be more limited on accessing this type of data.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Hi henry, you will need to go through some Login-SharedPreference-tutorials.  Volley is the best library to fetch json data. (User has to login from your login_activity page, otherwise it will be p.i.t.a. to get response data from webView / browser ). Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to load url to webview and check login is successful(onPageFinish also you can inject javascript to get direct json) then you can get data with asyncTask

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int
                errorCode, String description, String
                                            failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(context, description, Toast
                    .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view,
                                    WebResourceRequest req,
                                    WebResourceError error) {

            onReceivedError(view, error.getErrorCode(), error
                    .getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl
                    ().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
           HttpGetResources httpGet = new HttpGetResources(new AsyncResponse() 
   {

                @Override
                public void processFinish(Object output, Exception e) {
                    if (output != null) {
                        //do something
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, 
      getString(R.string.server_not_responding),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            Log.e("URL : ", URL);
            httpGet.execute(URL);
        }

    });

    webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

--AsyncTask Class--

```
     public class HttpGetResources extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {

    private AsyncResponse delegate = null;
    private static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
    private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private static final String RAW_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM- 
    dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz";
    private static final Gson GSON = new 
    GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(RAW_DATE_FORMAT).create();
    private Exception exception=null;
    private BufferedReader buffer = null;


    public HttpGetResources(AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        delegate = asyncResponse;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        delegate.processFinish(response,exception);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
        String stringUrl = params[0];
        Object result;
        try {
            URL myUrl = new URL(stringUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) 
            myUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
            connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            connection.connect();

            buffer = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            result = GSON.fromJson(buffer, TopHeadlines.class);
            buffer.close();
            buffer = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception=e;
            Log.e("ERROR : ",e.toString() + e.getClass());
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public Exception returnException(){
       return exception;
    }
}
```

---Interface Asyncresponse---

```
 public interface AsyncResponse {
  void processFinish(Object output, Exception e);
 }
```